# Visual Studio 2010, can simply including a new class trigger a release build bug?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Alright, I need a sanity check.

I was working on my project by starting to add a new class yesterday and decided to compile my progress so far. Upon executing a release build of the application I immediately noticed a bug. (Which in this case is an asteroid field not showing up for my game) This immediately confused me since I hadn't touched any code that could of created this bug. And everything else is rendered fine as usual.

Fast forward a day later and I think I've narrowed down the cause however it doesn't make any sense to me at all.

It only happens intermittently with release builds. (About 1 in 5 executions) But I can prevent it happening altogether by simply not including my new class in the project. Even though the class isn't being used or included by anything else in the project yet. I even went a step further and found just commenting out the class definitions and leaving the header is fine but the second I uncomment them it comes back. And for further testing I included it in an older build with the same results.

Would unused code affect the compilation of a release build? Does this sound like a Visual Studio bug? Or does it not make any sense at all? (In other words, did I just find a really convincing red herring?) Is there anything I can do to help figure out the source of this bug?

Comment: If you had undefined behaviour already in your program (that by bad luck you hadn't yet noticed) this could quite easily cause that undefined behaviour to become more obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would unused code affect the compilation of a release build?

Yes.  As [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6137734/960195) explains, Visual C++ keeps unused functions that aren't marked as inline.

> Does this sound like a Visual Studio bug?

It's unlikely, as I'll explain in answer to your next question.  Eric Lippert [explains](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/25/maybe-there-s-something-wrong-with-the-universe-but-probably-not.aspx) that, because the compiler is used so often that the easy and commonly seen bugs have already been found and fixed, it is *far* more likely that the bug is in your code than that the bug is in the C++ compiler.

> Did I just find a really convincing red herring?

Yes, I believe you did.  Without seeing the code for drawing the asteroid field, I can't be sure, but it's likely that you are dereferencing a bad pointer somewhere in there.  Now it starts to matter which data the pointer points to.

When the unused class is included in the compiled assembly, the memory devoted to your code is larger, which means that your heap has to start higher in memory, and a bunch of things move to higher addresses.  This means that a bad pointer can point at *different* data depending on whether the unused class is compiled into the executable or not.  When you dereference that pointer, then, you get different results.  That's why removing the code appears to "fix" the bug - whenever you take out the unused class, the bad pointer points at the data you want, rather than at other data.  As @awoodland rightly points out in the comments, you're really *unlucky* without the unused class and lucky with it, because you fail to find a bug that could manifest itself in all kinds of weird ways once you start distributing the code to your friends (or customers, if this is a commercial product).  These kinds of "bad pointer that happens to work" bugs can easily cause your code to appear to work correctly on some machines and fail dramatically on other machines, which is very difficult to debug.  Better that you found the bug now than later.

Comment: +1, that's the answer I was going to write although I'd say the opposite for *"you are lucky and the bad pointer points at the data you want, rather than at other data"* - it's *unlucky*, not lucky that a bug can be allowed hide undetected for any length of time.

Comment: @awoodland You're right about unlucky versus lucky.  I'll edit my answer to reflect that.